# Joining multiple tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example of the kind of join I'm trying to accomplish. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aab00/3.

You can see that there are records `(Name2, Name3)` that satisfy the `WHERE` clause but do not show up. Also the record for `Name1` that shows up isn't accurate.

Comment: you should put the condition on the `ON` clause because the `WHERE` clause filters after the records has been joined (*similarly works like an INNER JOIN*) while the `ON` clause filters the records before joining the tables. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aab00/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the aggregation before the `join`s:

```
SELECT t3.PersonName AS Name,
       COALESCE(t1.NumberOfCars, 0) AS NumberOfCars,
       COALESCE(TMobile, 0) AS TMobileConnections,
       COALESCE(ATT, 0) AS ATTConnections
FROM Table3 t3 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table1 t1
     ON t3.PersonSSN = t1.PersonSSN and t1.State = 'FL' LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (select t2.PersonSSN, t2.state,
             max(t2.Carrier = 'T Mobile') as TMobile,
             max(t2.Carrier = 'AT&T') as ATT
      from Table2 t2
      group by t2.PersonSSN, t2.state
     ) t2
     ON t3.PersonSSN = t2.PersonSSN and t2.State = 'FL';
```

You could also do the filtering by state in the subqueries, but this works for this query.

Note that I changed all the double quotes to single quotes.  Always use single quotes for string and date constants -- that is standard SQL.  Use double quotes or backticks for quoting identifiers, when needed.

Comment: add table alias with `TMobile` and `ATT`

Comment: @GordonLinoff this doesn't give me records for Name2 and Name3. Ideally they should also show up because they are also from "FL"

Comment: @Shan . . . Then add the `where` clause conditions to the `on` clause.